# Show spesific data with modal bootstrap in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

**Index.blade.php**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showModal" href="#" value="{{ route('member.show', $member->id) }}" class="text-secondary">Show data</a>
```

**Route:**

```
    Route::get('/member/show/{member}', 'MemberController@show')->name('member.show');
```

**MemberController**

```
 public function show($id) {
    $member = User::find($id);
    return view('menus.member.index', compact('member'));
}
```

**Modal in index.blade.php**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="showModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="showModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="clearData()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to make modal to show data in index.blade.php with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has cover that: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

On your button change `value` to `data-link=""`
Then in js:

```
$('#showModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var link = button.data('link') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  $.get(link).then(response => {
    //fill your modal with data
  })
})
```